# Address Field type insert in apex

Tags: apex, address

How can we insert a value into a address field type in apex class. My field api name is Address__c and type of the field is Address. I need to insert address info city, street, country etc into the field but i am getting error while inserting records into address field. Below is the apex code which i tried. Anyone have any idea what is the issue with my code.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?  Please [edit] your post to paste the code as text - it is hard to see the detail in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the address field name should not include the `__c` part, as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.caf_dev_guide.meta/caf_dev_guide/caf_dev_examples_apex.htm), instead should be something like: `Address__PostalCode__s`